# How can I transfer Optionsets/Extensions with Microsoft Xrm Sdk

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-365

I have a small tool for transfer Entities from microsoft dynamics 365 crm 2016 instance to another one. I succesfully transfered entities that don't have any dependices; but when i try to transfer entities that some optionsets  setted up -like language,verticals,departments- i get error beacause of these optionsets are not exists at target instance.

I signed these optionsets at below image. 
[image]

My problem is I don't know how i can retrive these extensions programatically. I already used  below code for retrive all optionsets but the user defined languages,verticals and other optionsets were not exists at repsonse.

```
  RetrieveAllOptionSetsRequest retrieveAllOptionSetsRequest = new RetrieveAllOptionSetsRequest();
        var retrieveAllOptionSetsResponse =(RetrieveAllOptionSetsResponse)sourceService.Execute(retrieveAllOptionSetsRequest);
```

Any Idea ? Which request should I send to source crm instance for get all user defined optionsets ?

Answer (score 1):

Those entities may have private option sets. You can retrieve using those option sets for each entity using these methods (pass the entity's logical name to the entity parameter):

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Metadata;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

    private List<AttributeMetadata> getPicklists(IOrganizationService svc, string entity)
    {
        return allAttributes(svc, entity).Where(a => a.AttributeType == AttributeTypeCode.Picklist).ToList();
    }

    //Retrieve all attributes of an entity
    private List<AttributeMetadata> allAttributes(IOrganizationService svc, string entity)
    {
        var req = new RetrieveEntityRequest();

        req.EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Attributes;

        req.LogicalName = entity.ToLower();

        var response = (RetrieveEntityResponse)svc.Execute(req);

        return response.EntityMetadata.Attributes.ToList();
    }
```